# Why Firefox cannot connect to a particular page on my local server but Chrome can?

Tags: google-chrome, tomcat, firefox

The application is working on my Local Tomcat server.  For some pages Firefox suspends, the status shows "Waiting for gg.google.com".  The same page is easily achieved by Chrome.

Also, I need to mention that some icons with URLs on the Web page are not present in my server, so Firefox is losing time trying to get them

Comment: Have you tried one of the many suggestions that come up when you google "Waiting for gg.google.com"? Some seem to refer to google maps, others to Firebug etc.

Comment: @OLAF, GOOD note: https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/waiting-for-gg-google-com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as Olaf Knock hinted, disabling JavaScript debugging in Firebug solved the problem. See https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2009/07/01/waiting-for-gg-google-com/